# Calling javascript object's own properties

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this object 'cp'. and it has got some properties like labels and arcSettings in it. Whenever i initialize this object and call the method 'graph()' it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

```
function cp() {             
        this.labels = [{
            "pointThickness": 0.8,
            "distance": 8,
            "textDistance": 7,
            "strokeColor": "#888",
            "strokeWidth": 0.5,
            "textColor": "#777",
            "pointColor": "#888",
            "textSize": 4,
            //"interval":100,
            //"precision":2,
            "num": 10,
            "startValue": 0,
            "endValue": 300
        }
        ];

        this.arcSettings = [
            {
               "totalArcAngle":300,
                "startAngle":(-this.totalArcAngle/2),
                "endAngle":(this.totalArcAngle/2),
                "progressValue":200,
                "radius":150,
                "thickness":30,
                "displayValue":this.progressValue
            }
        ];                   
}

cp.prototype.getOneUnit = function () {
    return oneUnit = (this.arcSettings[0].totalArcAngle) / (this.label[0].endValue - this.label[0].startValue);

}

cp.prototype.graph= function(){                     
var oneUnit = this.getOneUnit();

}

var cp = new cp();
cp.graph();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `cp.prototype.getOneUnit` function, you are using `this.label`. Instead, it should be `this.labels`.

```
cp.prototype.getOneUnit = function () {
    return oneUnit = (this.arcSettings[0].totalArcAngle) / (this.labels[0].endValue - this.labels[0].startValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first make an instance of the object

```
var cp = new cp();
```

Then add methods/properties into prototype

```
cp.prototype.graph= function(){ }
```

Also, you have used same name in both Class/Function declaration and object instance variable. You may change `function cp()` to `function Cp()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just made a typo. You wrote label instead of labels.